A group of old people seek to prolong their lives indefinitely after contact with an inimical being that seeks to torture their souls after they die
I am looking for a science fiction story published in the 1980's.
I may have read it in a science fiction magazine (IASFM, Analog, Galaxy) or anthology.
The plot description:
In the future, when humans have interstellar travel ability, a crew of humans encounter a planet containing two alien races.
The first race, builders, are aliens that long ago discovered an inimical super being that totally despises all other souls in the universe, and endlessly torments these souls once they are released from their physical bodies after death. To avoid this fate, the builders created a time stasis field in which to shelter and avoid death.
The builders also created a new race, caretakers, and set them to the task of finding a solution for the builders. The caretakers are immune from the dread of the torturer because they are soulless creatures.
After the human crew determine that the caretakers were created by the builders, they investigate and then achieve mental contact with the torturer.  Each crew member individually experiences an intense traumatic shock as the torturer turns its attention and hatred towards them and they fully realize what is in store for their souls after death.
They now understand and appreciate why the builders have created the time stasis field refuge - they are avoiding death until the caretakers can find some sort of solution. The human crew that have experienced contact with the torturer are now highly motivated to prolong their lives indefinitely and work on life extension methods until immortality can be achieved.

Were the two alien races called "Builders" and "Caretakers" in the story, or are you just using those terms as descriptions?

These terms are descriptions.

Thanks :-) It seems like a great idea for a story but I have ransacked my SF collection and found nothing. If there is anything specific you can remember, like a name used in the story, that might help jog my aging brain cells.

At the risk of blurring plot info from another story,
as I recall, the crew on returning to earth form a group called the "Red Council" and form commercial enterprises to pursue life extension.
Many years go by and the crew members are well into old age, but most have survived.
